# Calculate difference sequentially by groups in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, pandas-groupby

I'm trying to calculate the difference between two columns sequentially *as efficiently as possible*. My DataFrame looks like this:

```
category   sales   initial_stock
    1        2         20
    1        6         20
    1        1         20
    2        4         30
    2        6         30
    2        5         30
    2        7         30
```

And I want to calculate a variable `final_stock`, like this:

```
category   sales   initial_stock    final_stock
    1        2         20               18
    1        6         20               12
    1        1         20               11
    2        4         30               26
    2        6         30               20
    2        5         30               15
    2        7         30               8
```

Thus, `final_stock` first equals `initial_stock` - `sales` and the it equals `final_stock.shift()` - `sales`, for each category. I managed to do this with `for` loops, but it is quite slow and my feeling says there's probably a one or two liner solution to this problem. Do you have any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `groupby` and `cumsum` on "sales" to get the cumulative stock sold per category, then subtract from "initial_stock":

```
df['final_stock'] = df['initial_stock'] - df.groupby('category')['sales'].cumsum()
df
   category  sales  initial_stock  final_stock
0         1      2             20           18
1         1      6             20           12
2         1      1             20           11
3         2      4             30           26
4         2      6             30           20
5         2      5             30           15
6         2      7             30            8
```

Comment: Damn, that was fast. Thanks a lot, it worked like a charm. Seems I've still ways to go with more advanced uses of groupby